# What is the best emulator/environment for android debugging?

Tags: debugging, android, arm, dalvik

I know the question smells like *I want a ready solution* but I have been trying many things and after a lot of headaches, still I can't do what I want.

There are fast emulators but they don't provide good debugging features not even root privilege
and those who are designed for debugging are so slow and incapable of debugging games or even loading them, only tiny apps.

I tried some emulators but even after rooting, I can not push things like `dbg_server` into `/system/`.

I want to debug both dalvik and arm.
I'm so frustrated at this point. Can anyone give a list of what to install/do?

Comment: @serv0id, i meant an environment to run Frida in.
btw, i have done that. i may write a little guide how i did it for newbs like myself.